# Track elapsed hours in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-timestamp

I have a table in Google Sheets that I use to track the time elapsed between a `TIME IN` and a  `TIME OUT`.

As you can see below, my `TOTAL` formula in `D3` works, calculating the elapsed time from 5 AM to 3 PM as 10 hours. My formula in `D5` fails when calculating 7 PM to 2 AM, returning 17 hours instead of the correct elapsed time of 7 hours.

1. `TIME IN` and `TIME OUT` columns are formatted as automatic (time).
2. The `TOTAL` column is explicitly formatted as duration `[h]:mm:ss`
3. The formula in `D3` is

   ```
   =ABS(B3-C3)
   ```
4. The formula in `D5` is

   ```
   =ABS(B5-C5)
   ```

Why does the formula in `D5` return the wrong number of hours?

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  | **TIME IN** | **TIME OUT** | **TOTAL** |
| 3 | JIB | 5:00 AM | 3:00 PM | 10:00:00 |
| 4 | DIE | 0 | 0 | 0:00:00 |
| 5 | MA | 7:00 PM | 2:00 AM | 17:00:00 |

[image]

Comment: I added an ARRAYFORMULA version to [my answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/173567). It calculates multiple rows with a single formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

You need to adapt your formula to add 1 day (24 hours) to any **`OUT`** time that is less than the **`IN`** time.

## Formula

##### 1a.  Basic Duration Formula

```
= C3 + (C3  < B3) - B3          // Out + ([0]or[1] day) - In
                           // See 'F3' in the table.
```

##### 1b.  Return Number

```
= (C3 + (C3 < B3) - B3) * 24   // Multiply by 24 to return a number 
                          // instead of a duration. See 'G4' in table
```

##### 2.  Array Formula Duration Formula

Same as the **Basic Duration Formula** but will do the calculation for multiple rows.  Includes a basic ISNUMBER test to ensure that both **`IN`** and  `**OUT`** contain numbers.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF(ISNUMBER(B3:B) * ISNUMBER(C3:C), 
      C3:C + (C3:C < B3:B) - B3:B, ))
```

**FUNCTIONS:**  [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)  [IF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)  [ISNUMBER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296?hl=en)

## Compare Number Formats

Impact of different number formats on the same values.

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | **Format** | **In** | **Out** | **C – B** | **C + 1** | **E – B** | **F * 24** |
| **2** | Time **`h:mm am/pm`** | 7:00 PM | 2:00 AM | 7:00 AM | 2:00 AM | 7:00 AM | 12:00 AM |
| **3** | Duration **`[h]:mm`** | 19:00 | 2:00 | -17:00 | 26:00 | **`7:00`** | 168:00 |
| **4** | Number **`#,##0.000`** | 0.792 | 0.083 | -0.708 | 1.083 | 0.292 | **`7.000`** |

## Explanation

1. Sheets stores times (and durations) as the equivalent number of days.
   For example:

   ```
   = "2:00:00" + 0       // 2 hrs is 1/12 of 24 hrs
   =  0.08333...
    
   = "2:00 AM" + 0
   = 0.08333...           // 2 AM is 1/12 of the way through a day
   ```
2. Given the way Sheets stores times, for any given time, the equivalent number should be **`1`** larger (a day) than the same time on the previous day:

   ```
   Monday 2 AM - Sunday 2 AM = 1 (day)
   ```
3. Whenever **`OUT`**  falls on the next day, **`1`** needs to be added:

   ```
   # 2 AM (Monday) - 7 PM (Sunday)
    
   =  2/24  +  1  -  19/24
   =  7/24
   = 0.29166...       // Number 
   = 7:00:00          // Duration 
   = 7:00 AM          // Time
   ```
4. Sheets interprets boolean values as **`1`** or **`0`** in calculations. Since your durations are always less than 24 hours, the result from the boolean test **`OUT < IN`**  can be added to **`OUT`** which will effectively add **`1`** whenever **`OUT`** falls on the next day:

   ```
   +----------------------------+
   | FORMULA     = OUT + (OUT < IN) - IN    |
   +----------------------------+
          
   +----------------------------+
   | TRUE    IN:  7 PM, OUT:  2 AM      |
   +----------------------------+
   =   2/24  +  ( 2/24  <  19/24 )  -  19/24
   =   2/24  +  1  -  19/24
   =   0.29166...       // Number 
   =  7:00:00          // Duration 
   =   7:00 AM          // Time
    

   +----------------------------+
   | FALSE   IN:  5 AM, OUT:  3 PM      |
   +----------------------------+ 
   =   15/24  +  ( 15/24  <  5/24 )  -  5/24
   =   15/24  +  0  -  5/24
   =   0.41666...       // Number 
   =  10:00:00         // Duration 
   =  10:00 AM         // Time
   ```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! It was a bit confusing since im new to sheets formulas. I didnt know you could use ">" or "<" within paranthesis WITHIN arithmetic operations! Thank you again, and no, the time span wont be more than 24 hours.

Comment: @ZenLife18 Np! I'm sure I learned that on this site and try to share back the tips others taught me.  Do continue to participate on this site and pay it forward. 